# Using two PCs/Monitors with one set of input devices while gaming

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, synergy

I am usually gaming on my PC and wanted to use a second device while being ingame. I have a Surface Pro for this, which I can either use as a normal device, or as a second monitor via miracast. I have tried using miracast before, but it turns out that to use the second monitor I either have to leave the game or play in borderless fullscreen, which I dont want either of.

I have also tried mouse without borders, and I really liked the hotkeys to swap screen, but in games it had to minimize them or it would copy my commands to both PCs, making me ranomly shoot ingame.

Eitherways, I am looking for a better solution. I am aware of Synergy, but didn't purchase it yet as I have heard that it has similar issues. If someone can provide a solution or confirm those problems are fixed, I would be happy to try it out.

One solution would be something physical, like this [device](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01MXXQKGM), which is quite cheap, but I'm worried about the latency it would cause, which I can't find any information on.

Additionally, I would find a software solution much more convenient, so switching by pressing a macro key on my keyboard would be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to do the same as yourself - Didn't want two keyboards/mice etc - Synergy doesn't like gaming - I was never successful in my test which was Pause the game, go to other screen to open webpage, then back to game.

The best solution I came up with was using a logitech bluetooth (logitech-k780-multi-device)keyboard with two bluetooth radios - One button for gaming pc and other for the extra machine.

I had two mice, one gaming and one for extra machine but only one keyboard switchable manually between gaming. Once someone makes a bluetooth keyboard multi device with trackpad then it will be a perfect config.

Comment: Logitech also has multi device mice.